# .NET Micro Framework Tutorials?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-micro-framework

I can't really seem to find any good .NET Micro Framework Tutorials on google. Does anyone know of any?

Comment: Not many good .Net micro resources. This will definitely add to the SO knowledgebase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look here: http://informatix.miloush.net/microframework/, this site contains many examples, articles and resources you will find handy when developing for Micro Framework.

On that website there's a feed which aggregates all the feeds from all the blogs targeting .net micro framework, so you can stay in touch with the latest news from this field.

And if you are seriously interested in developing for this platform, you should get the book called Expert .NET Micro Framework. It is an excellent introduction with many examples and how-tos.

Answer (score 6):

Check Scott's Hanselminutes Session at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesOn9TheNETMicroFrameworkWithColinMiller.aspx

Answer (score 5):

As well as the earlier mentioned http://informatix.miloush.net/microframework/, You could check out the official [.NET Micro Framework portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/bb267253.aspx) on MSDN. 
It has some links to blogs with some good "Howto's"

Here's a ["getting started" tutorial](http://www.microsoft.com/netmf/about/gettingstarted.mspx) with some book recommendations

There's also an [unofficial community](http://www.microframework.nl/2008/12/29/net-micro-framework-wiki-youre-invited/) which may offer some help on the matter: http://wiki.microframework.nl

Answer (score 0):

A really good way for you to learn and understand the .NET micro framework is by using it for embedded software development. You can purchase a board called the Netduino available at http://www.netduino.com. You can work on some of the example projects mentioned on the web site or peruse online through the netduino forum community for more sample projects.

By doing hands on work, you can relate to the .net micro framework libraries in the context of real world embedded applications. This will be very useful to you and you will have fun learning it.